# What is undefined symbol: soap_wsse?

Tags: c++, soap, openssl

I am writing a library that uses both openssl and soap. I have build my project in linux, but when i try to load *.so created after building it throws an error like "undefined symbol: soap_wsse".

I know I am missing to include some library can anyone suggest me which one I am missing?

Comment: you could "ldd" your "*.so" to see if sth is missing.

Answer (score 0):

WSSE may be pre-OASIS version of Web Services Security (WSE) because I saw this namespace prefix in SOAP request and responses. WSE is a SOAP extension to apply security like auth tokens, signing and/or encrypting the SOAP message.
For example:

`<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
  xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">

     <wsse:UsernameToken>

        <wsse:Username xsi:type="xsd:string">
          B8ffemWZ1***hidden***wYJJW4bua0+</wsse:Username>

        <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordDigest"
          xsi:type="xsd:string">`.

Probably you're using a SOAP library which depends on a library that implements the standard WSE.

Anyway, Can you "grep" for the symbol "soap_wse" in libraries source code? Maybe this can get you a clue.